# terraform sub-module changes not being recognized in plan or apply

Tags: terraform

i have a terraform repo that looks something like this:

- infrastructure

  - global

    - main.tf

The `main.tf` file references a module in a remote repository:

```
module "global" {
    source = "git@github.com/company/repo//domain/global"
}
```

and the above module makes a reference to another module within the same remote repo: `main.tf`

```
module "global" {
        source = "git@github.com/company/repo//infrastructure/global"
    }
```

If i make a change in this module thats 3 levels deep, and then run `terraform get` and `terraform init` in the top level Terraform project followed by `terraform plan`, those changes aren't picked up.

Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i needed to do one of the following:

1) when running `terraform init`, i needed to pass the flag `upgrade=true`

2) or if running `terraform get`, i needed to pass the flag `update=true`

this downloads the latest versions of the requested modules